# How to disable stripe pay button when payment is processing using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

> I have created using reactjs stripe card section and in card section, adding card element and in the checkout form render it and in checkout form pay button is also there but I want to disable the pay button unless response gets from backend?
>   Here is my code:-

```
class CheckoutForm extends React.Component {
  handleCallback = status => {
    if (status === "success") {
      message.success("Payment is successfull");
      this.props.history.push("/main");
    } else {
      message.error("Some error occoured");
    }
  };

  handleSubmit = ev => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const { userDetails, user, tempPassDate } = this.props;
    const { paymentId } = this.props;
    this.props.stripe
      .createPaymentMethod("card", { billing_details: { name: "Jenny Rosen" } })
      .then(({ paymentMethod }) => {
        console.log("Received Stripe PaymentMethod:", paymentMethod.id);
        this.props.payment(
          {
            paymentMethodId: paymentMethod.id,
            paymentId: paymentId,

          },

        );
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
  render() {

    return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <CardSection/>
            <button>
              Pay
            </button>
          </form>             
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can handle by using ternary operator to disable the button on the basis of state change like if you adding loading there then add below code **{this.state.loading == true ? disabled : null }**

Answer (score 0):

Manage that in state like:

```
class CheckoutForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      disableBtn: false;
    }
  }
  handleCallback = status => {
    if (status === "success") {
      message.success("Payment is successfull");
      this.props.history.push("/main");
    } else {
      message.error("Some error occoured");
    }
  };

  handleSubmit = ev => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ disableBtn: true });
    const { userDetails, user, tempPassDate } = this.props;
    const { paymentId } = this.props;
    this.props.stripe
      .createPaymentMethod("card", { billing_details: { name: "Jenny Rosen" } })
      .then(({ paymentMethod }) => {
        console.log("Received Stripe PaymentMethod:", paymentMethod.id);
        this.props.payment(
          {
            paymentMethodId: paymentMethod.id,
            paymentId: paymentId,

          },

        );
        this.setState({ disableBtn: false });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
  render() {

    return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <CardSection/>
            <button disabled={this.state.disableBtn}>
              Pay
            </button>
          </form>             
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it's working but the problem is that when the backend response is very slow then again pay button is enabled and again payment is processing means at a time 2 times button was clicked.